# Why toilet paper is softer in moist air?

Tags: water, air, molecules

After a hot shower,the air from the bathroom is full of water steam,right?

How does the air affect the texture of the toilet paper?I mean,the toilet paper it seems to be softer,but ***why?***

Can someone explain me,please?

Answer (score 2):

You could think of this in terms equilibrium processes. The shower increases the partial pressure of water in air and that pushes the equilibrium of water condensing on the surface in the forward. There may also be some capillary action if the adsorbed water can form small liquid droplets. As more water seeps into the tissue the stress-strain properties of the material will change due to the presence of water clusters in between the strands and fibres of the natural polymers.